# Using REGEXP_LIKE function in Oracle DB

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I want to validate a string. The conditions are :

1. It should be 9 chr long.
2. first character should be alphabet(in *uppercase*).
3. remainig chr should be between *0* and *9*
4. No special character is allowed

I want to verify this using `REGEXP_LIKE()`. Please suggest.

Comment: OK. what have you attempted, and where are you stuck?

Comment: regexp_like(string, '^[A-Z][0-9]')

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to use the following REGEXP_LIKE to validate your inputs:

`REGEXP_LIKE(td.text_value, '^[A-Z][0-9]{8}$')`

Explaining the regular expression:

- `^` - Beginning of String
- `[A-Z]` - A Capital Letter
- `[0-9]{8}` - Exactly 8 digit characters
- `$` - End of String

Here is a query validating certain use cases:

```sql
WITH test_data (text_value) AS
(
  SELECT 'A12345678' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 'a12345678' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 'A1234567' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 'A123456789' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT '$12345678' FROM DUAL
)
SELECT td.text_value, 
       CASE WHEN REGEXP_LIKE(td.text_value, '^[A-Z][0-9]{8}$') THEN 'Y' ELSE 'N' END AS VALID
FROM test_data td
```

Here is the link to Oracle's Regular Expression documentation ([Link](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/Oracle-Regular-Expression-Support.html#GUID-969230D6-FC1A-4C75-BF2A-6B1BE909DED6))

Additionally, here is a DBFiddle running the above query ([Link](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=bf01b00ab6a0f479f912ae1fad873573))

Comment: Thanks a lot for quick response...Its really helpful